# Can PowerShell identify which drop down selection a user makes in a Word Document?

Tags: powershell, ms-word, ms-office

After selecting an option from a drop down menu, and saving the document, can PowerShell identify which selection was made?

Comment: Have you attempted scripting anything?

Comment: I think you are asking if a PowerShell module or logic can be used as a Word macro or "plugin".

Comment: PowerShell *is* capable of manipulating COM objects, which Word documents are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PoSH, to monitor real-time for timestamp changes of the doc file (WMI Event stuff), but it sounds like you are trying to use PoSH as a document tracker. That's really not a thing. This is why MSWord has the document tracking feature.

PoSH has no idea what happened in an MS Word does interactively. Let alone when a user has developed a MSWord application/form. You have to use the MSOffice DOM.

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
```

Even with that, that means you are physically opening each target doc one at a time to examine it. You'd use MS Word Visual Basic for Applications or a Macro to do this sort of thing along with having MS Word document change tracking turned on.

If you are doing this in a text file for example, you could use Get-Content with the -tail.

For Example:

```
Get-Content -Path $latest.FullName -tail 0 -Wait | Out-GridView -PassThru
```

The above would monitor a text file real-time, and OGV will show the changes as they are saved. Again, text file only. Trying this a MSOffice doc, will just bring back garbage. So, again, back to using MSO DOM.

Lastly, the only other way I can imagine this, is using a custom created COM Add-in (VSTO) and Hosted PowerShell. As a former MSOffice, Dev. I can tell you; if you've never done it, it's a good deal of work to get it right, it at all.